# count interval length with overlap in a larger data

Tags: python, dataframe, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of tuples representing genomic intervals, where each tuple contains the start and end coordinates of the interval. I want to compute the total length of all the intervals, but I need to account for overlapping regions only once. The problem is that the intervals may not be sorted, and some intervals may overlap with multiple others, making it difficult to determine which overlaps should be counted. For example, consider the following list of intervals:

for example:

```
#sorted data by start pos 
[(3, 9), (3, 5), (6, 9)]
```

The last interval overlaps with the first one, but not with the second one, and so the correct total length should be 6 (not 9 or 10). How can I write a Python code to solve this problem in an efficient way?

Note that this is a large data sheet, may have a lots of intervals

Comment: So what does `[5, 3]` stand for? Should reverse intervals count? Also, those are not tuples, but lists. It should be `[(3, 9), (5, 3), (6, 9)]`.

Comment: sorry, I have updated this question, (3, 5) stand for one interval start at pos 3 and end at 5, I know some tools `bedtools merge` can do this, but I need this function work as a part of my python code, so I need to write a implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by start, keep track of how far you've reached:

```
intervals = [(3, 9), (3, 5), (6, 9)]

total = 0
reached = float('-inf')
for start, end in sorted(intervals):
    if end > reached:
        start = max(start, reached)
        total += end - start
        reached = end

print(total)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7NCsIwDL7nKXJbixsIQ1Fhvoh4KLZlhdmOLAx9@tp2o@byJfl@kvnLY/D9ZaYYnWdDq5oWHPAh@havssWMp4znPD8BOLCakuIIZNRrNDr1dgqKRdM5bxsJNhAurIhbNF6j87gEYqNFPSBvgKmcLYI77knbNlexp@C3@og9atfIqtkeOQwlo9sslfz/lliAmdJtURwyxh8)